# Webpack cannot handle Semantic-UI .css files?

Tags: css, webpack, semantic-ui

Using Webpack, I want to minimize and bundle the semantic.css file available [here](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui/2.2.12/semantic.css).

Webpack doesn't throw any any error messages, however the outputted css has slight differences from the inputted css. (The CSS doesn't work the same.)

[this validator](https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/validator.html.en#validate_by_input) says the file is full of errors. (However, it's working well when directly used in a browser). Is it the reason it is not working with Webpack?

Here's part of my webpack.config.js file:

```
output: {
        path: __dirname + '/publicProduction/v2/bundle/',
        filename: '[name]'
    },
    resolve: {
        modules: ['node_modules']
    },
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                query: {
                    presets: [
                        'es2015',
                        'stage-0'
                    ],
                    plugins: []
                },
                exclude: /node_modules/
            },
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                    fallback: 'style-loader',
                    use: ['css-loader', 'postcss-loader']
                })
            },
            {
                test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2|png|jpg|jpeg|gif)$/,
                loader: 'file-loader?name=resources/[name].[ext]'
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('./[name]'),
        new Webpack.ProvidePlugin({
            $: 'jquery',
            jQuery: 'jquery',
            'window.jQuery': 'jquery',
            'window.$': 'jquery'
        })
    ]
```

Comment: Did you import this css to your css? or Did you add to your HTML?

Comment: @TanDuong I add directly to my HTML.

Comment: Can you show your HTML?

Comment: @TanDuong since I was not getting an answer here, I opened an issue here: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/6990  please let me know if you have an idea :) thanks!